# How many possible passwords are there with these restrictions?

Tags: permutations

Assume that a legal password is $10$ characters long, using the following $3$ types of symbols: $26$ alphabets, $10$ digits and $6$ special characters (such as ! and *). In addition, it must use at least $2$ of these types of symbols. How many legal passwords are there?
Repeat the previous question with the additional condition that using only digits and special characters is not allowed.

I believe it's a permutation with repetition. Because of the restriction on the first part of the equation, I want to take out all cases where only one type of character is used. So, my answer would be $42^{10} - 26^{10} - 10^{10} - 6^{10}$. For the second part of the question, I think the number of cases where only digits and special characters are used is $16^{10}$ so I would just subtract that from my original answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer to the first question is correct.

In the second question,  you subtracted the passwords consisting only of digits and those consisting only of special characters *twice*. So the correct answer is $42^{10}-26^{10}-16^{10}$.